# Delete rows from two tables related

Tags: sql, delete-row

Between table1 and table2 there are an 1 N relation. "code" column of table2 is foreign key of table1.
I want to delete all rows in table1 who don't have any row related in table2. I try

```
delete * from table1 r 
   inner join table2 a 
      where (r.code!=a.code)
```

but this delete all rows in two tables...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this is what you want?

```
delete from table1
where code not in (
  select code from table2
)
```

before you run the delete you might want to verify that the correct rows will be deleted using a select query:

```
select * from table1
where code not in (
  select code from table2
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try this:

```
delete from table1 r 
where not exists (select 1 from table2 a where r.code = a.code);
```

Comment: @jpw Thanks I copied the statement from the question and didn't notice that

Answer (score 0):

Or probably using a `RIGHT OUTER JOIN`

```
delete from table1 r 
   right join table2 a on a.code = r.code
      where r.code is null
```